# API of Dockerized Spring Boot app unreachable

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I'm facing an annoying problem and hopefully someone can give me a hint.

I wrote a Spring Boot app which runs locally (not in Docker), then I have Kafka and Zookeeper in Docker containers. The communication works perfectly.

Now, I dockerized the Spring Boot app and when I try to call it (http://localhost:8080/kafka/health-check) from the host laptop, I get 404.

The Java class:

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
@RequestMapping("kafka")
public class RestController {
    (...)
    @GetMapping("health-check")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> healtCheck() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

The Docker file exposes the port:

```
FROM openjdk:11
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/spring-boot-kafka-producer-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

The Docker Compose too:

```
services:
  zookeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      # Connect to Zookeper
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeper:2181
  spring-boot-app:
    image: spring-boot-app
    container_name: spring-boot-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

I still get 404 even when I run:

```
docker exec -it spring-boot-app curl spring-boot-app:8080/kafka/health-check
```

I can't call the API neither from outside Docker nor inside the Docker container, so I must be missing something small somewhere.

Comment: Have you checked the logs for the app to see that it's running?

Comment: It's running that there are no logs about the failed request @SoftwareEngineer

Comment: You may want to install netstat in container & check if the 8080 really open.

Comment: @atline That doesn't explain why the curl doesn't work. Am I doing executing it correctly?

Comment: YES, this doesn't explain, just want to confirm if port 8080 really open by your `java -jar app.jar`, just to narrow ...

Comment: Yes, you're doing everything correctly. Is your spring app configured to listen to 8080 inside the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the jar wasn't up-to-date. For some reason, IntelliJ would execute the app but not generate the jar. The problem was solved running `mvn clean install`

Comment: Don't write your own Dockerfile... And especially don't use fat jars in Docker. `mvn spring-boot:build-image` will create an (optimized) image for you without any Dockerfile

Comment: @OneCricketeer Why shouldn't I write my Dockerfile? It's just a test project....

Comment: Like I said, Springboot can do that for you. It's a waste of time, even for a test project, and it creates a more optimized image